# C#: assign 0xFFFFFFFF to int

Tags: c#

I want to use HEX number to assign a value to an int:

```
int i = 0xFFFFFFFF; // effectively, set i to -1
```

Understandably, compiler complains.
Question, how do I make above work?

Here is why I need this.
`WritableBitmap` class exposes pixels array as int[]. So if I want to set pixel to Blue, I would say: 0xFF0000FF (ARGB) (-16776961)

Plus I am curious if there is an elegant, compile time solution.

I know there is a:

```
int i = BitConverter.ToInt32(new byte[] { 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF }, 0);
```

but it is neither elegant, nor compile time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You just need an [unchecked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a569z7k8%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) cast:

```
unchecked
{
    int i =  (int)0xFFFFFFFF;

    Console.WriteLine("here it is: {0}", i);
}
```

Comment: As a side note, if you're looking to flip all bits the best, most concise, way to do this is `int i = ~0;`

Comment: Thanks you for that correction, Mr. Lippert. This constant is an unsigned int because it can't be represented as an int.

Answer (score 89):

Give someone a fish and you feed them for a day. **Teach them to pay attention to compiler error messages and they don't have to ask questions on the internet that are answered by the error message.**

```
int i = 0xFFFFFFFF;
```

produces:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'uint' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists 
(are you missing a cast?)
```

Pay attention to the error message and **try adding a cast**:

```
int i = (int)0xFFFFFFFF;
```

Now the error is:

```
Constant value '4294967295' cannot be converted to a 'int' 
(use 'unchecked' syntax to override)
```

Again, pay attention to the error message. **Use the unchecked syntax.**

```
int i = unchecked((int)0xFFFFFFFF);
```

Or

```
unchecked
{
    int i = (int)0xFFFFFFFF; 
}
```

And now, no error.

As an alternative to using the unchecked syntax, you could specify `/checked-` on the compiler switches, if you like to live dangerously.

Bonus question:

> What makes the literal a `uint` in the first place?

The type of an integer literal does **not** depend on whether it is hex or decimal. Rather:

- If a decimal literal has the `U` or `L` suffixes then it is `uint`, `long` or `ulong`, depending on what combination of suffixes you choose.
- If it does not have a suffix then we take the value of the literal and see if it fits into the range of an `int`, `uint`, `long` or `ulong`. Whichever one matches first on that list is the type of the expression.

In this case the hex literal has a value that is outside the range of `int` but inside the range of `uint`, so it is treated as a `uint`.

Comment: My question was how to make it work, not "why does it break". I assumed "Understandably, compiler complains" will indicate that I understand the issue. Original error doesn't suggest using unchecked syntax. I haven't tried putting a cast on it, because I knew that wouldn't have worked.

Comment: @user93422: If you understood the issue, you wouldn't have had to ask the question.  You asked the question, therefore you didn't understand the issue.

Comment: @user93422: "I haven't tried putting a cast on it because I knew that wouldn't have worked" - how could you know that without trying? The compiler explicitly told you you need a cast there, and it was right.

Comment: @Greg D -- I came here looking for exactly the same answer.  I also understood the issue, but was unaware of the 'unchecked' syntax being a novice C# programmer.  BTW, the error message I'm getting is "overflow in constant value calculation", which offers none of the help to solve the problem relied upon in the answer.

Comment: @EricLippert:  Your comment "The type of an integer literal does not depend on whether it is hex or decimal." -is the best answer to understand the situation. Normally people compare binary representation of the literal (-1)  and the literal representation (4294967295)

Comment: When would a hex value not be used as a bit-pattern? Even error codes are handed around all the time, and it's expected we interpret them as bit-patterns.

Answer (score 3):

The unchecked syntax seems a bit [gar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gar)'ish (!) when compared to the various single-letter numerical suffixes available.

So I tried for a [shellfish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellfish):

```
static public class IntExtMethods
{
    public static int ui(this uint a)
    {
        return unchecked((int)a);
    }
}
```

Then

```
int i = 0xFFFFFFFF.ui();
```

Because the lake has more fish.

Note: it's not a constant expression, so it can't be used to initialize an enum field for instance.